# ServiceStack 4.5 configure log4net programmatically

Tags: servicestack, log4net

I am starting a new project with ServiceStack 4.5. Is there any way to configure log4net programmatically? In the documentation I found

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);
```

I added this to the constructor of the AppHost class. However this seems to assume that you put the configuration to the App.config file (I am doing self-hosting on a windows service).

In some other projects I wrote a singleton and then used the Log4Net API to do the configuration:

```
   private static void CreateFileAppender(ref Logger bedInventoryLogger, string logFilePath, Level logLevel, int maxFileSizeInMb, bool filterNh)
    {
        var filePatternLayout = new PatternLayout
        {
            ConversionPattern = "%date; [%thread]; %-5level; %logger; [%type{1}.%method]; - %message%newline"
        };
        filePatternLayout.ActivateOptions();
        var bediLogFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
        {
            File = logFilePath,
            AppendToFile = true,
            MaximumFileSize = $"{maxFileSizeInMb}MB",
            MaxSizeRollBackups = 5,
            RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
            LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
            Layout = filePatternLayout,
            StaticLogFileName = true,
            Threshold = logLevel
        };
        if (filterNh)
        {
            bediLogFileAppender.AddFilter(new LoggerMatchFilter
            {
                LoggerToMatch = "NHibernate",
                AcceptOnMatch = false
            });
            bediLogFileAppender.AddFilter(new LoggerMatchFilter
            {
                LoggerToMatch = "NHibernate.SQL",
                AcceptOnMatch = false
            });
            bediLogFileAppender.AddFilter(new LoggerMatchFilter
            {
                LoggerToMatch = "FluentNHibernate",
                AcceptOnMatch = false
            });
        }
        bediLogFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
        bedInventoryLogger.AddAppender(bediLogFileAppender);
    }
```

Since I used several logs, appenders etd and wanted to turn off NHibernate logging (I am using NHibernate 4 as ORM) etc. I found it more convenient to do configuration in C# than in XML.

Is it possible to hook this in with ServiceStack or do I better use Log4Net directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default ServiceStack Log4Net adapter doesn't allow you to inject a configured Log4Net instance however the adapter classes are easy to copy and modify which are just in this 2 files which basically just forward the calls to Log4Net:

- [Log4NetFactory.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net/Log4NetFactory.cs)
- [Log4NetLogger.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net/Log4NetLogger.cs)