# ServiceStack Log4NetFactory

Tags: servicestack

How can I configure log4net in code when I like to use the servicestack logging interface? I see there is

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net:true);
```

If I got things right this expects a XML file containing the Log4Net configuration. I avoid XML config files whenever possible and usually configure Log4Net with my own static `LoggerConfig` class. There I setup all my appenders (EventLog, File, Console, etc.) using the Log4Net API.

Is there any way to integrate my class with the ServiceStack logging interface?

Comment: Sorry wrong post, please ignore. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753202/servicestack-4-5-configure-log4net-programmatically